# Poetry + Sphinx + Cython

Tags: cython, python-sphinx, packaging, python-poetry

I use poetry to build my cython package. I have NumPy-style docstrings in all functions and classes. What I want to do now is to add Sphinx automatic documentation and publishing it at Read the Docs.

I have read this thread [How do I use Sphinx with Cython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057476/how-do-i-use-sphinx-with-cython) and understand that first I have to compile my .pyx files. However when I call `poetry build` in the end I get only .tar.gz and .whl files and no .pyd or .so ones.

So the question is following: are there any ways to insert callbacks in poetry build process so that when calling with some argument the docs generate automatically?

I will also appreciate links to packages, that use poetry, sphinx and cython together, so that I could learn from them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written a small tutorial with example. You can find it here: https://github.com/iamishalkin/cyrtd

Important points:

Add readthedocs.yml

```
version: 2

python:
  install:
    - method: pip
      path: .
      extra_requirements:
        - docs
    - method: pip

sphinx:
  configuration: docs/source/conf.py
```

Add dependencies to pyproject.toml:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.7"
cython = "^0.29.13"

sphinx = { version = "^2.2", optional = true }
sphinx_rtd_theme = { version = "^0.4.3", optional = true  }

[tool.poetry.extras]
docs = ["sphinx", "sphinx_rtd_theme"]
```

In the dashbord on ReadTheDocs activate "Install Project" checkbox

There is one inelegant workaround with `setup.py`. If you know, how to overcome this problem, please, let me know.