# How to use Sphinx in a Python project that depends on being built in place?

Tags: c++, makefile, cython, python-sphinx

I have a large mostly Python project that I am trying to document. Part of this project is dependent on C++ source code which is made accessible via Cython.

When running the code like normal it runs fine, but in trying to do auto documenting with Sphinx I have run into issues. I think   [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20472798/11637415) had the right idea, but I cant make it work.

My `Makefile` looks like this

```
# Minimal makefile for Sphinx documentation
#

# You can set these variables from the command line, and also
# from the environment for the first two.
SPHINXOPTS    ?=
SPHINXBUILD   ?= sphinx-build
SOURCEDIR     = .
BUILDDIR      = _build

# Put it first so that "make" without argument is like "make help".
help:
    @$(SPHINXBUILD) -M help "$(SOURCEDIR)" "$(BUILDDIR)" $(SPHINXOPTS) $(O)

.PHONY: help Makefile

# Catch-all target: route all unknown targets to Sphinx using the new
# "make mode" option.  $(O) is meant as a shortcut for $(SPHINXOPTS).
%: Makefile
    @$(SPHINXBUILD) -M $@ "$(SOURCEDIR)" "$(BUILDDIR)" $(SPHINXOPTS) $(O)
```

How can I tell Sphinx to run `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` and then reference the output `.so` file(s) before analyzing the code?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to add the step from the [answer you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057476/how-do-i-use-sphinx-with-cython/20472798#20472798) as part of the Makefile generated from sphinx to before any sphinx specific command was executed.

```
# Minimal makefile for Sphinx documentation
#

# You can set these variables from the command line, and also
# from the environment for the first two.
SPHINXOPTS    ?=
SPHINXBUILD   ?= sphinx-build
SOURCEDIR     = .
BUILDDIR      = _build

# Put it first so that "make" without argument is like "make help".
help:
    @$(SPHINXBUILD) -M help "$(SOURCEDIR)" "$(BUILDDIR)" $(SPHINXOPTS) $(O)

.PHONY: help Makefile

# Catch-all target: route all unknown targets to Sphinx using the new
# "make mode" option.  $(O) is meant as a shortcut for $(SPHINXOPTS).
%: Makefile
    @cd /path/to/setup.py; python setup.py build_ext --inplace
    @$(SPHINXBUILD) -M $@ "$(SOURCEDIR)" "$(BUILDDIR)" $(SPHINXOPTS) $(O)
```

Adding it above the catch-all command that sphinx generates means that the build command to generate cython code would be executed prior to the the sphinx related command.

I would suggest instead to structure the [project directory to be more standard](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/) to what is used in python. Instead of having documentation be in the same directory as the source code instead have a separate directory for source code and documentation.

```
root directory/
  myproject/ (source code for Cython module)
  libs/ (generated .so files from Cython)
  tests/ (directory to hold test cases that should run after building)
    __init__.py
  docs/
    Makefile (from sphinx)
  Makefile (project)
  setup.py
```

The Makefile for the project would be responsible for building the source code and then building the documentation. Its Makefile would look similar to below:

```
.all:
    @python setup.py build_ext 
    @cd tests; $(MAKE) python -m unittest
    @cd docs; $(MAKE) html
```

The first part of `all` would generate the source code (and should be updated to place the .so files generated to the `libs/` folder). The second part would go into the `tests/` directory and run unittests (example with python's unittest library). The third part would go into the `docs/` directory and run make for the target html using the Makefile generated by Sphinx. To do this you would also want to update the tests and docs to include `libs/` in their path so that way they can import the `.so` files generated from the build.  (Note: @ symbol prevents the line from being output to the console. This should be omitted if it is desired to be seen as part of a build)