# Cython: Autogen docs with either Sphinx or Doxygen *without* compiling

Tags: cython, python-sphinx, doxygen

I've got a few light cython `.pyx` files that I have regular docstrings written in that I want to be able to autogen Sphinx documentation for.

I know how to do this utilizing Doxygen through breathe, and how to do it with regular docstrings through `sphinx.autodoc`, but I can't seem to get either of them to parse a cython file.

If I compile the Cython file with the `embedsignature=True` flag enabled, then it's fine, but this is a very large project that needs its documentation page updated regularly without having to rebuild the entire thing.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/q/10057476/407651?

Comment: What you are asking for is not possible with Sphinx, which does not parse .py or .pyx files directly. Autodoc imports Python modules. Doxygen on the other hand works by parsing source code, so maybe you can use it for Cython files.